# all columns on the right have disappeared

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I don't know what happened but I have no columns after column E on my spreadsheet. What can I do to add a column on the right without having to insert a new one between D and E and having to copy the content from E to the new one?
[image]

Comment: If you hover over the top right hand border of Column E (Top right in your picture) does a line with 2 arrows appear?

Answer (score 2):

On the right corner of E cell, there would be double line. You can mouse hover to that and drag and release. All column will appear.
[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KzHo.png)

Comment: didn't see you reply but that's what I did thank you

Answer (score 0):

The columns have been hidden and you need to unhide them. To do that,

- hover the mouse over the right hand border of the column label until it changes to a double arrow with two vertical lines
- right click and select **Unhide**

Comment: if that helped, please mark it as the answer as explained in the [Tour]